# How to refresh datagridview with button?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, refresh

I am very new to VB and I have been tasked with writing a program for my work.
I have an MS access DB and in the program I have a gridView.

I created a refresh button but I can't seem to get it to update anything.
The database is on a network drive. When I restart the program it gets the data but will not refresh.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Can you please share the code that you already have ? That should be a good starting point for other to review your stuff..

Comment: Live_Pass_DownDataGridView.DataSource = Nothing
        Interactive_live_pass_downDataSet.Reset()
        Dim cmd As New sqldataadapter
        cmd = "I:\interactive live pass down.accdb",con
        con.open()
        cmd.fill(Interactive_live_pass_downDataSet) inter 
        Live_Pass_DownDataGridView.DataSource = DataSet(0).defaultview

Answer (score -1):

When click on the "Refresh Button" that you have created. Call the bindgrid() function. It should go database get the data and bind to the datagrid again.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: No point helping you since you simply defame people reputation point before you can really understand what I trying to explain to you.

Answer (score -1):

Protected Sub btnRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click

BindGrid()

End Sub

Comment: Just re-call the function. It will perform that function again and rebind the grid.

Comment: I guess what i need to do is go back to the mapped drive and fetch new data

Comment: wow rude.  What is says when I put it inside the refresh button is it's not declared.

Comment: Please solve the question yourself since you simply defame people point while you cant read and understand people answer. good luck

Comment: if you are talking about the -1 thing that's not me. I cant even do that yet since i dont have the reputation needed.

Comment: I dont understand why your getting all upset. I simply asked for help and help understanding and you want to attack me and belittle me. If you didnt want to help then you shouldn't have responded.

Comment: You were no help but thanks. I found out how to do it on my own. Me.Live_Pass_DownTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Interactive_live_pass_downDataSet.Live_Pass_Down)